# How to check if user is authenticated with CAS server?

Tags: restful-authentication, cas, restful-architecture, rubycas

I need to check if user is authenticated in the system in a PHP application that is not a PHPCas client. Does the RubyCAS server provide API for this? How do you make secure communication in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the problem is the gateway feature of the CAS protocol. This feature will redirect a user to a [CAS server](http://techslate.net/checking-user-authentication-in-cas/) so that the user’s browser can be authenticated via the initial ticket-granting cookie given to it the first time the user submitted credentials. If the ticket-granting cookie is found, then the CAS server will redirect the user back to the app without having to re-enter credentials.  Read more at Techslate about this [user authentication](http://techslate.net/checking-user-authentication-in-cas/) solution

Comment: if i am requesting the tgt via rest call, then how will i check if the user is authenticated at the cas server.